# Assigning output parameter from Stored Procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Please help me with the following scenario

I need to call a Stored Procedure inside another one. the inner SP would return a number value which I need to store it in a local variable.

rough code

```
AssignSpResult NUMBER;
```

AssignSpResult = SPtobecalled(Param1,Param2, OutParam);

This syntax is most probably wrong, so please help correct it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of how it might be:

```
HR\XE> create or replace procedure Proc1(p_out out number)
  2    is
  3    begin
  4      p_out := 123;
  5*   end;
HR\XE> /

Procedure created.

HR\XE> create or replace procedure Proc2
  2    is
  3      l_val number;
  4    begin
  5      Proc1(l_val); 
  6      dbms_output.put_line('Here is a value returned by Proc1: ' || to_char(l_val));
  7    end;
  8  /

Procedure created.

HR\XE> set serveroutput on;
HR\XE> exec Proc2;

Here is a value returned by Proc1: 123                                            

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Depending on your needs it might be more convenient to use functions to return a result of a procedural processing of data. Here is an example:

```
HR\XE> create or replace function F1 return number
  2    is
  3      l_ret_value number;
  4    begin
  5      l_ret_value := 123;
  6      return l_ret_value;
  7    end;
HR\XE> /

Function created.

HR\XE> create or replace procedure Proc3
  2    is
  3      l_val number;
  4    begin
  5      l_val := F1;
  6      dbms_output.put_line('Value returned by the F1 function: ' || 
                              To_Char(l_val));
  7    -- Or
  8      dbms_output.put_line('Value returned by the F1 function: ' || To_Char(F1));
  9   end;
HR\XE> /

Procedure created.

HR\XE> set serveroutput on;
HR\XE> exec proc3;

Value returned by the F1 function: 123
Value returned by the F1 function: 123

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

HR\XE>
```

Answer (score 3):

A stored procedure does not return a value it takes IN, OUT or IN OUT parameters. So probably your have to call:

```
SPtobecalled(Param1,Param2, AssignSpResult );
```