# Why doesn't TRANSLATE function work in sql developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to test the translate function out:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNCTION1 RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
BEGIN

TRANSLATE('222tech', '2ec', '3it');
  RETURN NULL;
END FUNCTION1;
```

But in sql developer it doesn't seem to work right, it returns:

```
Error(4,1): PLS-00221: 'TRANSLATE' is not a procedure or is undefined
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning output parameter from Stored Procedure in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780864/assigning-output-parameter-from-stored-procedure-in-oracle)

Comment: Long story short: a function _returns_ a value; you need to assign that value to a variable. Having said that, your code doesn't make much sense. Why are you returning NULL? What are you trying to do here? It's not clear at all... Why are you even using PL/SQL? You can do this all in SQL more easily and more efficiently.

Comment: @Ben - Hmm, Ok I will study up some more. Yeah I am somewhat in "learning" phase surely. thanks!